# Are there similar documents in English about "How to integrate music examples with open source tools in scientific documents"?

Tags: music, scientific-notation, musicology

By chance I encountered this tutorial in German: "[Musikwissenschaft mit LATEX](http://kreincke.github.io/mycsrf/examples/latex-musicology.pdf)". It investigates on 121 pages various ways to typeset notes and scientific notations. In contrast to [latex4musicians](https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/info/latex4musicians/latex4musicians.pdf) it focuses on scientific publications, e.g. with functional analysis, looks at front- and backends and workflows. (*Subtitle translated:* How to integrate music examples with open source tools in scientific documents)

I like it. But it might not be accessible to anybody in our community, interested in typesetting music.

It looks like the author (Karsten Reinecke) provided this on Github: [Musicology in and with LaTeX - a self referantial tutorial, written in German](https://github.com/kreincke/mwm.ltx)

So: Are there similar publications in English?

**Title**:
[image: Title]

**Example**:
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Such a document may be found on CTAN: http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex4musicians/latex4musicians.pdf.

Comment: welcome to tex,=.sx.

Comment: Unfortunately that‘s the one I cited, with remarks. So, no, that’s not matching.

Comment: Sorry, hadn’t seen the link… I thought I had looked enough!

Comment: No problem, we‘ve all been there.