# How to convert MIDI to MusiXTeX with LaTeX?

Tags: music, musixtex

For example, I want to convert MIDI to MusiXTeX staves!
But I really don't know how to do it, do let me know if you do!

Comment: There are several processors to make MusicXML from MIDI (e.g. MuseScore also can import MIDI and export MusicXML, Mozart should also be able to do so, but I've never used it). For MusicXML to MusiXTeX there is, i.e. the limited converter [`mx2mt`](https://github.com/jirka-grunt/mx2mt).

Comment: Alternatively, many music notation programs are able to import midi and export lilypond.

Comment: See also here for an investigation, unfortunately in German, which touches the midi topic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661862/245790